# How to prevent windows from repositioning when laptop screen closed?

Tags: nvidia, laptop, screen

I am running Unity on Ubuntu 18.04 but this issue has been happening for previous releases.

I am using an ASUS UX303U notebook with an Nvidia GEFORCE video card.  It is on 24/365. I position my various windows to work with them at a 3200x1800 resolution. All windows display nicely. When I close the laptop lid/screen the computer is set to not suspend.

When I next open the lid/screen, all windows are either reset in size or at minimum positioned towards the left top of the screen and on top of each other.

What appears to be happening is that at one point in the process of re-activating the screen, the resolution changes for a brief moment and at that point Ubuntu resizes and repositions all open windows to fit into the new screen resolution. The resolution then changes to my set resolution but the various windows that were repositioned and resized to fit the lower resolution that happened momentarily stay in their positions and sizes and are now piled on top of each other. I am now forced to resize and reposition every window manually and it drives me nuts.

The issue seems related to closing the lid/screen as automatic blanking of the screen and subsequently entering my password to bring the screen back does not seem to cause this issue.

Any help or work-around (short of never closing the lid) would be greatly appreciated.

Output from `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1620, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 2880x1620+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     60.00 +  59.96    59.94    48.01  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97* 
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1600x900_60.0 (0x410) 118.250MHz -HSync +VSync

  h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1856 total 2112 skew    0 clock  55.99KHz
  v: height  900 start  903 end  908 total  934           clock  59.95Hz
```

Another ASUS laptop with a maximum resolution of 1920x1080 does not go through this kind of a screen reset.

After more testing, I now believe that something I installed at one time is interfering and this issue is related only to my specific setup. It is probably easier to either re-install from scratch or live with the issue.

Comment: Yes, for that particular output of xrandr the resolution was set to 2880x1620 but the issue is not dependent on resolution.  The system seems to actually behaving just like it should in the case of a resolution change. The question is more "why does the system temporarily switch screen resolution in the process of coming back from a closed lid state ?"

Comment: Even at a resolution of 1920x1080 which works fine on the other ASUS laptop, this laptop switches to a lower resolution momentarily . Just before the screen returns, there is a blank page with just the pointer. The pointer changes size indicating a resolution change and then the screen comes up at the requested resolution.

Comment: I just noticed that on the low resolution laptop that works as expected, the startup of the display does not show a momentary blank screen with just the mouse pointer on it like the high resolution laptop. It would appear that there is an extra step that gets performed just before the screen comes on that causes this resolution switch. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start a search for commands that are processed by the system just before the display pops up.

Comment: laptop-mode-tools is not installed, turning off all options under power management did not change the outcome of closing the lid and reopening it.

Comment: Other laptop is an ASUS UX305F and is using "ubuntu" as a display manager (as indicated by the menu that pops up if you click on the little star thing below the password box on the login screen.) It uses an Intel HD Graphics 5300 video system.

Comment: It turns out that the laptop that is giving me problems shows that it is also using "Ubuntu" display manager rather than Unity as earlier reported. Under 'Graphics' in the 'Details' section of the settings dialog it says 'llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0,256 bits)' even though the sticker on the computer says 'Nvidia GEFORCE'

Comment: I have discovered an interesting work-around: If a window extends past the physical screen on any side, the effect of closing and opening the lid will still change the resolution momentarily but the window will stay in it's position and keeps it's size!

Comment: I think this is an Nvidia driver issue. Try switching drivers or driver options (`man nouveau`). If that doesn't help, I would write a script to resize all the windows with `xdotool`. Also, consider integrating information in comments into the question.

Comment: I installed the nvidia driver ppa and installed the latest driver (nvidia-390) but there was no change. I am not capable of writing a script but thanks for your help. I will live with my work-around.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 with either proprietary or nouveau drivers. Its exactly what OP says, closing/opening the lid temporarily reduces the resolution, which subsequently screws up window sizing / positioning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works for me [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/closing-the-laptop-lid-changes-the-display-resolution/36871/2)

> Change **IgnoreLid=false** to **IgnoreLid=true** in this file:
>
> `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`